# Trying to use nested views in angularjs with ui-router get a blank page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, states

My setup

app/learning/learning.js

```
 angular.module('meanApp')
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('learning',{
    templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.html',
    url: '/learning',
    controller: 'LearnCtrl',
    views: {
     'list': {
       templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.list.html',
       controller: function($scope){  }
     },
     'magic': {
       templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.magic.html',
       controller: function($scope){  }
     }
   }
 });
});
```

app/learning/learning.html

```
<h1>Learning</h1>
<div ui-view="list"></div>
<div ui-view="magic"></div>
```

app/learning/learning.list.html

```
<p>A list</p>
```

app/learning/learning.magic.html

```
<h2>Magic</h2>
```

when I navigate to /learning I get a blank page, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't load the base template inside state when there are nested `ui-view`,
Define the base template inside `views`.

**Route Code**

```
 angular.module('meanApp')
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('learning',{
    url: '/learning',
    views: {
     '': {
       templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.html',
       controller: 'LearnCtrl'
     },
     'list@learning': { //you missed state name here
       templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.list.html',
       controller: function($scope){  }
     },
     'magic@learning': { //you missed state name here
       templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.magic.html',
       controller: function($scope){  }
     }
   }
 });
});
```

This could Help you, Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, that has been bugging me for ages!

Comment: @Cherry15 You're welcome, it would be great if you marked answer as correct.

Comment: Sorry, just discovered the tick next to the answer, I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: @Cherry15 np. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was trying to load the base template inside state and I missed out the state name as Pankaj said, so the solution is...

```
angular.module('meanApp')
.config(function($stateProvider) {
 $stateProvider
 .state('learning',{
   url: '/learning',
   views: {
     '': {
     templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.html',
     controller: 'LearnCtrl'
    },
    'list@learning': { //you missed state name here
     templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.list.html',
     controller: function($scope){  }
    },
    'magic@learning': { //you missed state name here
     templateUrl: 'app/learning/learning.magic.html',
     controller: function($scope){  }
    }
  }
 });
});
```